# A Vector Surface Integral (flux)

Tags: vector-fields, multiple-integral

Evaluate $\iint_{S}\vec{A}.\vec{n} ds$ ,where  $ \vec{A}= (x+y^2) \hat{i} -2x\hat{j} + 2yz \hat{k} $ and S is the surface of the plane 2x+ y +2z =6 in the first octant.

Where I stand :

I have tried to do this problem but couldn't go far as I was unable to find the differential area. My friend shared an interesting idea that what we essentially calculate is the flux and flux through the axis planes should be the flux through surface. I agreed, but She calculated it for only the xy plane (which matches the answer in the book) But shouldn't we also calculate the flux contributed by the other two surfaces (yz ,zx)? I will share the solution given by my friend.
[My friend's Soln.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/asT6L.jpg)

Comment: I see your friend's solution. Why do you think that is the flux through XY plane? Do you notice the normal vector that your friend used? How else were you planning to do it?

Comment: First , I think it is flux due to the fact I have encountered Electric fields and they are written in a similar fashion .Second,I think it is the flux through XY plane because she integrates over the triangle which is a shadow on the XY plane. What I think she calculates is the flux that enters perpendicularly to the xy plane. I would say we have to do the problem again using the same method taking $dz*dx/j^.n^$ and take the shadow of the surface in the zx plane, likewise for the zy plane.Intuitively I think this makes sense.I am not sure of the normal vector,I assumed it is for the projection

Comment: There is no more calculations through $YZ$ plane etc. I see dot product of $\vec{F}$ with the unit normal vector to the plane $2x + y + 2z = 6$. So it is clearly flux through the surface $2x + y + 2z = 6$ by given bounds in the first octant. What you may be  getting confused with is how the surface is being parametrized and how we are getting to $\Delta S$ through projection on $XY$ plane.

Comment: Hmm, Yeah I think you are right by my logic my normal should be k hat . I should seriously refer some material . Thank you for your time.